# Is there any benefit to setting encoding of mail to base64?

Tags: joomla-3.4, emails, jmail

Using the JMailer class, it possible to easily send out a mail using the Joomla API. One of the options I don't know too much about is the encoding part:

```
$mailer = JFactory::getMailer();
$mailer->Encoding = 'base64';
```

What is the benefit of using this?

Answer (score 2):

This encoding is designed to make binary data survive transport through transport layers that are not 8-bit clean, such as mail bodies.

Base64-encoded data takes about 33% more space than the original data.

**Example:**

```
<?php
  $str = 'This is an encoded string';
  echo base64_encode($str);
?>
```

**Result:**

```
VGhpcyBpcyBhbiBlbmNvZGVkIHN0cmluZw==
```

Source: http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php